# Difference between /select & /query handlers in solr

Tags: solr

I want to know what is exact difference between /select & /query handlers in solr.

For /select handler, query is formed like.

```
/solr/collection/select?q=lalit&wt=json
```

which gives less results.
[image]

But for /query, its 
    /solr/collection/uery?q=lalit&wt=json

which gives much more results.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer to this depends on the contents of your `solrconfig.xml`, as that is the configuration file where the different requestHandlers are defined. If you search that file for `<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">` and `<requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">`, you should be able to find what the difference is.

There is no different handling of those two internally in Solr, and their behaviour are always configured in `solrconfig.xml`. The default configuration in solrconfig.xml from the `example/solr` directory does this by setting a value for `df` (the default search field) to `text` (meaning that different fields are searched depending on which end point you point your search to).

You can configure your own definitions, such as `/queryfoo`, `/bar` etc. with different presets if you have a need in the future, although most settings are usually supplied by the client.